# VB.net file handling progresses to slowly

Tags: vb.net

Hi i have a app that takes a list of files and searches each file for all the images referenced within each file. When the list is finished I sort and remove duplicates from the list then copy each item/image to a new folder. It works, but barely. I takes hours for the copying to occur on as little as 500 files. Doing the copying in windows explorer if faster, and that defeats the purpose of the application.
I don't know how to streamline it better. Your inputs would be greatly appreciated.

```
    'Remove Dupes takes the list of images found in each file and removes any duplicates

Private Sub RemoveDupes(ByRef Items As List(Of String), Optional ByVal NeedSorting As Boolean = False)

    statusText = "Removing duplicates from list."
    Dim Temp As New List(Of String)
    Items.Sort()

    'Remove Duplicates
        For Each Item As String In Items
        'Check if item is in Temp
        If Not Temp.Contains(Item) Then
            'Add item to list.
            Temp.Add(Item)
            File.AppendAllText(ListofGraphics, Item & vbNewLine)
        End If
    Next Item

    'Send back new list.
    Items = Temp
End Sub

'GetImages does the actual copying of files from the list RemoveDup creates

Public Sub GetImages()
    Dim imgLocation = txtSearchICN.Text
    ' Get the list of file
    Dim fileNames As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imgLocation)
    Dim i As Integer
    statusText = "Copying image files."
    i = 0
    For Each name As String In GraphicList
        i = i + 1
        ' See whether name appears in fileNames.
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        ' Search name in fileNames.
        For Each fileName As String In fileNames
            ' GraphicList consists of filename without extension, so we compare name
            ' with the filename without its extension.
            If Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) = name Then
                Dim FileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
                ' Debug.Print("FileNameOnly: " & FileNameOnly)
                Dim copyTo As String
                copyTo = createImgFldr & "\" & FileNameOnly
                System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, copyTo)
                File.AppendAllText(ListofFiles, name & vbNewLine)
                'items to write to rich text box in BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged
                imgFilename = (name) + vbCrLf
                ImageCount1 = i
                ' Set found to True so we do not process name as missing, and exit For. \
                found = True
                Exit For
            Else
                File.AppendAllText(MissingFiles, name & vbNewLine)
            End If
        Next
        status = "Copying Graphic Files"
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 * i / GraphicList.Count())
    Next
End Sub
'BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged. gets file counts and writes to labels and rich text box

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    '' This event is fired when you call the ReportProgress method from inside your DoWork.
    '' Any visual indicators about the progress should go here.

    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    lblStatus.Text = CType(e.UserState, String)
    lblStatus.Text = status & " " & e.ProgressPercentage.ToString & " % Complete "
    RichTextBox1.Text &= (fileFilename)
    RichTextBox1.Text &= (imgFilename)
    txtImgCount.Text = ImageCount1
    Label8.Text = statusText
    fileCount.Text = fCount

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change something in your code to avoid the constant writing to a file at each loop and the necessity to have two loops nested.

This is a stripped down version of your GetFiles intended to highlight my points:

```
Public Sub GetImages()

    ' Two list to collect missing and found files
    Dim foundFiles As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Dim notfoundFiles As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

    Dim fileNames As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imgLocation)

    ' Loop over the filenames retrieved
    For Each fileName As String In fileNames

        ' Check if the files is contained or not in the request list
        If GraphicList.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)) Then

            Dim FileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
            Dim copyTo As String
            copyTo = createImgFldr & "\" & FileNameOnly
            System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, copyTo)

            ' Do not write to file inside the loop, just add the fact to the list
            foundFiles.Add(FileNameOnly)
        Else
            notfoundFiles.Add(FileNameOnly)
        End If
    Next

    ' Write everything outside the loop
    File.WriteAllLines(listofFiles, foundFiles)
    File.WriteAllLines(MissingFiles, notfoundFiles)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I'll implement this and look at my loops.